# Removing Header tags including envelope, body etc

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am having a souce XML in which I need to remove the Header tags and sort of extract a sub-XML from the main XML. Below is my input -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ " xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema " xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance " xmlns:n="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ " xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:event="some namespace" xmlns:head="some namespace">
    <soap:Header>
        <head:someHeader>
            <!--content-->
        </head:someHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <event:parent>
            <child>
                <!--internal content-->
            </child>
        </event:parent>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And below is my expected output -

```
        <parent>
            <child>
                <!--internal content-->
            </child>
        </parent>
```

First I am doing Identity Transformation and then trying to remove Envelope and Body but it doesn't seems to be working. Here is my attempt which is not working -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" exclude-result-prefixes="soap">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="soap:Envelope/soap:Header"/>
    <xsl:template match="Envelope/Body">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: With various namespaces being declared on the root element of the XML input I think your samples don't really explain what you want to achieve, the `head` prefix from `head:someHeader` is not declared at all, the input has a `event:parent`, the result only a `parent`, the contained content is only shown as a comment. Normal "extraction" of a subtree would preserve and keep all namespaces so you need to spell out in more details which changes you want to perform.

Comment: If you really use XSLT 2.0 then in some places using `copy-namespaces="no"` might help, but for the `event:parent` to `parent` change it won't suffice, you need to write a template matching and transforming that element. And of course `match="Envelope/Body"` only works with input elements in a namespace if your XSLT 2 has `xpath-default-namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the above. The thing is I have shared dummy data as I cannot share actual data and that is why I forgot declaring `head`. I have edited it. 
Coming to the next point - I need to remove the namespaces and extract a sub-XML from the input XML which I am not able to achieve. 
I want to extract the `parent` tag and its child data and remove `event` namespace from the same. Hope this clears it out a bit.

Comment: Your XML has `xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ "` with an extra space at the end. That's not the same as the (correct) `xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"` declared in your stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you guys, I used @michael's answer and `#all` from @MartinHonnen's answer to exclude all namespaces as I didnt need any of them. Thanks to both of you, cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do simply:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:event="some namespace"
exclude-result-prefixes="soap event">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/soap:Envelope">
    <parent>
        <xsl:copy-of select="soap:Body/event:parent/*" copy-namespaces="no"/>
    </parent>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzknsY

Answer (score 1):

You can select the `event:parent` element, transform it and copy the rest

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="some namespace"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//parent"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parent">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```